# Problem with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

A small car rental company has two cars, which are rented per day. The amount of applications for each day is Poisson distributed with rate parameter $\alpha = 1.5$.

a) What percentage of days are both cars not rented?

b) What percentage of days are both cars rented?

**Attempt:** I know that  $$ P(X = j) = \frac{\alpha^j}{j!} e^{-\alpha}. $$ For the first question, I did $1 - P(X = 2) = 1 - \frac{(1.5)^2}{2} e^{-1.5} = 0.74898.$

But my textbook gives the answer to a) as $0.2231$ and to b) as $0.4422$.

I'm not sure how to derive these results, and where my mistake lies. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both cars are not rented if they get zero applications, so you need $$p(x=0)$$ for the first part.

both cars are rented if they get two or more applications, so you need $$p(X\geq2)=1-(p(X=0)+p(X=1))$$ for the second part

Comment: For the second part, is it $P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X \leq 2) = 1 - (P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + P(X =2))$ ?

Comment: @Kamil: see my edited answer